# How to use absolute imports with firebase functions with shared folders?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use absolute imports in a project with shared folders between the `firebase-functions` folder and the `frontend folder`.

Everything works great during development mode, but I keep getting a error when I try to deploy.

I have the following folder structure:

```
functions
  - src
  - index.ts
  - tsconfig.json
common
 - src
app
 - src
firebase.json
```

functions/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@functions/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@common/*": ["../common/src/*"]
    }
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src", "../common"]
}
```

and the following firebase.json:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": ["node_modules", ".git", "firebase-debug.log", "firebase-debug.*.log"],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build",
        "node ./functions/predeploy.js"
      ],
      "postdeploy": ["node ./functions/postdeploy.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use absolute imports I get stuck at:

> Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module '@common/features/FEATURE_NAME'
> Require stack:...

Any ideas on how ot fix it?

Comment: The CLI only deploys code within the functions folder.  Everything else is ignored and is not available while running in Cloud Functions.  You need to make sure that all code is available in the deployment. Cloud Functions will pull in dependencies by running `npm install`, and that's the only hook you get.